# override an element in a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, overriding, element

I have the following problem:

I have a list with 9 positions and I have this function 
 `putPiece(Piece, Board, Line, Column)`
that puts a Piece in a Position Line, Column of a Board (the list of 9 positions)
I'm trying to check if any position is already filled so that I don't try to put anything in it since it isn't possible (right?)
can you please help me make a function `checkIfFree(Board, Line, Column)` that check is the position (Line, Column) of the board is already occupied or not...

Comment: I think you should post more of your code - including how you represent your board.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that a free position is represented by a free variable `var(X)` should solve the problem.